# VBA division by Last value

Tags: excel, vba

I have table like this

```
Column A    Column B
 5            25
 4            20
 8            40
 3            15
20           100
```

[image]

I want to use vba script to select last Value from Column A to divide like `=A1/last Value Form coumn A*100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy down.

```
=A1/LOOKUP(2,1/A:A,A:A)*100
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking out for a Solution in `Excel-VBA`, then here it is..

```
Sub test()

Dim result As Variant
Dim firstvalue As Variant
Dim secondvalue As Variant
firstvalue = Range("A1").Value
secondvalue = Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
result = (firstvalue / secondvalue) * 100

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA. It uses an array which is quick and does the entire column as shown.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DivideByLastValue()
    Dim lastRow As Long, arr(), i As Long, divisor As Double
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Value
        divisor = arr(UBound(arr, 1), 1)
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 2) = arr(i, 1) / divisor * 100
        Next
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```